# Removing "microsoft reserved" volume

Tags: external-hard-drive

When tried opening my 'Mac' format Hard-disk (WD My Passport 25E2 Media) in windows PC, the Windows could not access the file stored in the Hard-disk. By mistake "Microsoft reserved" volume has been created in my hard-drive. After this incident, I could not access my external hard drive in my MacBook/Mac. 'Disk Utility' side list in my MacBook shows only 134.2 MB volume (disk2s1) and the entire volume is missing and not accessible.

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk2s1
```

How can I safely access my stored files without damaging the data stored in the hard-disk? 
If suggested I can delete/erase the Microsoft reserved volume.

Note: 
1. I don't have time machine backup in my Macbook. Even my Time machine backup is stored inside the external hard-drive.

Comment: Have you tried a live Gparted or Parted Magic to mount this drive without one of your OSes locking it for use? A simple indication of what flags this drive has running could help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was it encrypted? If it was, you can probably forget recovery. If it wasn't you *may* have some slim chance with a disk recovery utility, but Time Machine volumes can really confuse them because of all the hard links. They think they can recover 10TB from a 1TB drive. You will, of course, need another drive to recover to.

To read & write HFS+ disks on Windows you need a 3rd party utility, such as [Paragon's HFS+ for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/)